# Длина строки типа System::String^

Tags: visual-c++, строки, c++-cli

Доброго всем времени суток. Подскажите, как получить длину строки типа System::String^?

Например

```
String^ a = L"qwertyu";
```

Получить нужно 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, это CLI. Используйте свойство [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.length.aspx).

```
int n = a->Length;
```